# Is there a way to automatically let the width of button (div) change when less buttons are defined?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to let the width of certain divs (used for buttons) automatically change when I'm defining more or fewer buttons.

The code I've got is just a simple menu. Which can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/65cw791g/).

If there is a way to get such a solution (to save work for when creating larger menus)?

CSS:

```
    /*Main Container*/
.mc {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
/*Menu Button*/
.mb {
  width: 90%;
  height: 4%;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000000;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 14px;
    margin: 4px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/*Columns*/
.c1 {
  float: left;
  width: 12.5%;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="mc">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="c1">
        <form>
          <input target="_self" type="button" class="mb" value="Button 1" onclick="window.open('#')">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="c1">
        <form>
          <input target="_self" type="button" class="mb" value="Button 2" onclick="window.open('#')">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="c1">
        <form>
          <input target="_self" type="button" class="mb" value="Button 3" onclick="window.open('#')">
        </form>  
      </div>
      <div class="c1">
        <form>
          <input target="_self" type="button" class="mb" value="Button 4" onclick="window.open('#')">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="c1">
        <form>
          <input target="_self" type="button" class="mb" value="Button 5" onclick="window.open('#')">
        </form>  
      </div>
      <div class="c1">
        <form>
          <input target="_self" type="button" class="mb" value="Button 6" onclick="window.open('#')">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="c1">
        <form>
          <input target="_self" type="button" class="mb" value="Button 7" onclick="window.open('#')">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="c1">
        <form>
          <input target="_self" type="button" class="mb" value="Button 8" onclick="window.open('#')">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Further details:
I'm making this as a project for my own use. This will be a private photography blog and is currently a way of experiencing how one-page web designs are created and to acquire knowledge for future web development.

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify what you want to get in the end?

Comment: I got a notification that I couldn't post the question without more words, though the question itself was pretty clear. Don't mind the paragraph at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with flex

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <button>Hey</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button>Hi</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button>Hoop</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  display: flex
}
.col {
  width: 100%;
}
button  {
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: This is putting my buttons below each other and thus does not fix the issue for the width.

Comment: This answer actually does work, even in IE, which baffles me a bit. Also, column widths are usually used in tandem with flex-grow / flex-shrink properties to allow only certain columns to be able to grow / shrink when something is added or removed.

Comment: You do realize that the code in my question refers to buttons that are side by side next to each other and his code just makes a list of buttons, right? Therefore this answer (although the code itself works) does not solve the problem I stated above.